# Cannot induce exit code 3 from psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

The [docs page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) states (emphasis mine)

> ### Exit Status
>
> psql returns 0 to the shell if it finished normally, 1 if a fatal error of its own occurs (e.g. out of memory, file not found), 2 if the connection to the server went bad and the session was not interactive, **and 3 if an error occurred in a script and the variable ON_ERROR_STOP was set.**

However, I seem to be unable to induce exit code 3.

```
bash-4.2$ uname -a
Linux mvpg-centos-76.vagrantup.com 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bash-4.2$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.12
bash-4.2$ psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -c 'select 1/0;'
ERROR:  division by zero
bash-4.2$ echo $?
1
bash-4.2$
```

I've also reproduced this behaviour on FreeBSD 11.3 and Darwin 19.3. Am I misunderstanding the documentation or using a faulty syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it to work a few ways:

```
postgres@ironforge:~$ cat onerrorstop.sql 
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
select * from gurumeditationerror;
postgres@ironforge:~$ psql -f 'onerrorstop.sql'
psql:onerrorstop.sql:2: ERROR:  relation "gurumeditationerror" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from gurumeditationerror;
                  ^
postgres@ironforge:~$ echo $?
3
postgres@ironforge:~$
```

and:

```
postgres@ironforge:~$ echo "\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
> select * from smellyfarts;" | psql
ERROR:  relation "smellyfarts" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from smellyfarts;
                  ^
postgres@ironforge:~$ echo $?
3
postgres@ironforge:~$
```

and:

```
postgres@ironforge:~$ cat onerrorstop.sql 
select * from gurumeditationerror;

postgres@ironforge:~$ psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on -f 'onerrorstop.sql' 
psql:onerrorstop.sql:1: ERROR:  relation "gurumeditationerror" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from gurumeditationerror;
                      ^
postgres@ironforge:~$ echo $?
3
postgres@ironforge:~$ 

Version:

    postgres@ironforge:~$ psql --version
    psql (Post greySKULL) 9.5.19
    postgres@ironforge:~$
```

Comment: @PeterVandivier: you could put that into `.psqlrc` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.18.10

Comment: @PeterVandivier yes, answer edited

Comment: ah... so it seems `-v` & `-c` together prevent exit code 3, but `-v` & `-f` allow it